# Add users to events in the Shared calendar and invite specific people

Tags: calendar

My requirement is that , the administrator of site creates an event on the calendar. The built-in add event workflow does not allow to invite someone . It just creates an event.
Is it possible to invite someone for the event by adding them by name ?

Comment: Is it possible ? Any answers ?

Answer (score 1):

Running into the same problem and looking for the answer as well.  I believe it is because it is a shared calendar and that function did not get migrated to 2013? (shared vs. public are not synonymous) There is a work around, but it is not pretty.

You can create your event in your private calendar in Outlook.  Once the invite has been accepted you can copy the event to the public calendar through Outlook.  Not pretty but it is the only solution I have found thus far.